# Proper way to override Mysql my.cnf on CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mysql

Context: I'm porting an opensource server software (and writing associated documentation) from Debian/Ubuntu to CentOS/RHEL.

For the software to run correctly, I need to add a dozen of specific parameters to Mysql configuration (example: increase `max_allowed_packet`).

From a Debian point of view, I known I can override Mysql's my.cnf by adding a file to `/etc/mysql.d`, say `/etc/mysql.d/my-software.cnf`.

**My question is**: how to do the same correctly on CentOS/RHEL ?

Other infos:

- I know where mysqld looks for its configuration file thanks to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html. But, for CentOS, I don't understand:

  - how NOT to directly edit `/etc/my.cnf` (that may not be package-update-proof)
  - where to add my specific Mysql parameters
- Reading the CentOS Mysql init script (`/etc/init.d/mysql`), I've seen that a `/etc/sysconfig/mysqld` is sourced, but I don't know how to add configuration parameters.
- I've search for combinations of override / my.cnf / centos on ServerFault, StackOverflow and also DBA.StackExchange, but found nothing relevant.
- I make all the tests within a "centos:6" Docker container
- the software is Asqatasun https://github.com/Asqatasun/Asqatasun

Comment: Why are you using centos 6 rather than centos 7? This is just going to add three and a half years of technical debt instantly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton to widen the audience, some users still have conservative upgrade policies. But as our base is Debian/Ubuntu, if centos6 is not feasible, we will certainly switch to centos7

Comment: On CentOS 7, you would just stick everything in `/etc/my.cnf.d` like you do now. This wasn't set up on 6.

Comment: And as for conservative, EL 6 is [past the end of Production 1](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata), which is about the time you should stop deploying it for new projects. Doing anything greenfield on EL 6 right now is steadily moving away from "conservative" and toward "insane".

Comment: @MichaelHampton I didn't know that Redhat document, really interesting, thanks! I have arguments now, we will switch to 7.

Comment: Why use CentOS 6 ? CentOS 7 is in 7.1 version and very stable. why MySQL ? Why don't use MariaDB ? You can find the last MariaDB version on SCL : https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-mariadb100/ With this SCL you can find a /etc/opt/rh/rh-mariadb100/my.cnf.d MySQL is bad for an OS project, use Maria.

Comment: @llaumgui Good catch for MariaDB, we will switch.

Comment: @MichaelHampton your second comment was the good answer. Thanks. I let you move it as a regular answer, that I will validate as the good one :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `strace -e open /some/prog/name`, e.g. `strace -e open mysql` would reveal what places are checked for configuration directives and in what order for each particular OS and a program version. Different programs use different location and sections within a configuration.

As to overriding, you can only be sure that CentOS/RHEL installs and uses `/etc/my.cnf`. If software your are porting uses libmysqlclient, you may take the path of overriding [MYSQL_HOME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html) environmental variable. If not,  adding `!include /some/location.cnf` to [client] section of /etc/my.cnf is still an option.